# How long can algae survive with no air recycling (closed bottle)

Tags: photosynthesis, cellular-respiration, chloroplasts

In a small bottle nearly filled of Chlorella in water and grow medium, how long would it take for them to die (with or without light).

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Calculate the oxygen in the bottle, calculate how much oxygen the Chlorella will use all together per second = time.  Best I can give you with no specifics provided.